How to Complete PayPal Express Checkout in a Headless Shopware 6 Store Without Redirect to PayPal Confirmation?
I've implemented the PayPal Express Checkout for my headless Shopware 6 store following Shopware's official example. However, I’m running into issues on the last step, where they use fetch() to call the redirectUrl. This approach doesn’t work for me because the redirectUrl response is HTML and triggering a fetch on it doesn’t redirect the user to PayPal as intended.
Here's my current workaround: Instead of using fetch(), I redirect the user directly to the redirectUrl. This opens the PayPal interface again for a second confirmation and while it does mark the order as paid in Shopware, it adds unnecessary steps for the user.
How can I complete the PayPal Express Checkout flow without needing to redirect to the redirectUrl for a second confirmation at PayPal? What steps should I follow to mark the order as paid in Shopware after handlePayment without this extra redirect?
<PayPalScriptProvider
  options={{
    clientId: "<myClientId>",
  }}
>
  <PayPalButtons
    createOrder={async () => {
      // Create order --> PayPal
      // POST /store-api/paypal/express/create-order
      // return response.data.token
    }}
    onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
      // Prepare Checkout --> PayPal
      // POST /store-api/paypal/express/prepare-checkout { body: { token: data.orderId }}
      
      // Update context --> set paymentMethodId to PayPal
      // POST /store-api/account/register { body: { paymentMethodId: <paypalPaymentMethodId> }}
      
      // Create order --> Shopware
      // POST /store-api/checkout/order
      
      // Handle Payment --> Shopware/PayPal
      // POST /store-api/handlePayment 
      // { query: {isPayPalExpressCheckout: true, paypalOrderId: data.orderId } body: { orderId: <shopwareOrderId>, finishUrl: 'https://...', errorUrl: 'https://...' } }
      
      // Redirect to the redirectUrl from the handlePayment endpoint --> re-confirmation at PayPal
    }}
  ></PayPalButtons>
</PayPalScriptProvider>

In this setup, redirecting to the redirectUrl after handlePayment opens PayPal again, prompting the user to confirm the payment a second time. Only after this second confirmation does Shopware mark the order as "paid" instead of "unconfirmed."
